# Find ID coordinates

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have 2 files,

```
1) A B       2) A,chr1,startA,endA
   C D          B,chr1,startB,endB
   B A          C,chr1,startC,endC
                D,chr1,startD,endD
```

My desired output,

```
A chr1 startA endA B chr1 startB endB
C chr1 startC endC D chr1 startD endD
B chr1 startB endB A chr1 startA endA
```

My try gives me the chr,start and end for the 1st ID, but I dont know how to associate and append also for the 2nd ID.

```
f1=open('input1','r')
f2=open('input2','r')
output = open('out.txt','w')
dictA= dict()
for line1 in f1:
    listA = line1.strip('\n').split('\t')
    dictA[listA[0]] = listA
for line1 in f2:
    new_list=line1.rstrip('\r\n').split(',')
    query=new_list[0]
    chrom=new_list[1]
    start=new_list[2]
    end=new_list[3]
    if query in dictA:
        listA = dictA[query]
        output.write(str(listA[0])+'\t'+str(listA[1])+'\t'+chrom+'\t'+start+'\t'+end+'\n')
 output.close()
```

Comment: This looks a bit like BED format; except but what are 'A','B' etc.?

Comment: gene ID's..I just wrote A B for simplicity

Comment: Well don't add gene ID's before the chromosome number, they should go after as the Name, see the official extended BED format spec: https://genome.ucsc.edu/FAQ/FAQformat#format1

Comment: Are you sure that, in the second file, the "key" for each line fits completely into the first character of the line, or may there be additional characters?

Comment: yes, but I dont need BED format, I need to get start and end point for each of my ID's...

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: What you're doing with file2 (splitting on comma, reading up to the 6th field) doesn't match the format you gave the file in (4 columns, whitespace-separated).

Comment: I edited. Posted like that before bcos I suppose one from the script can get an idea of how the format is..1st file is tab-separated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your desired output, I think that you may be going about this slightly backward. It seems like it would make more sense to store the contents of the *second* file in the dictionary and then use the contents of the first file to look up the data in the dictionary, like so

```
import io

f1 = io.StringIO('A\tB\nC\tD\nB\tA\n')
f2 = io.StringIO('A,chr1,startA,endA\r\nB,chr1,startB,endB\r\nC,chr2,startC,endC\r\nD,chr1,startD,endD')

dictA = dict()
for line in f2:
    temp = line.strip().split(',')
    dictA[temp[0]] = temp[1:]

for line in f1:
    id1, id2 = line.strip().split('\t')
    print('\t'.join([id1] + dictA.get(id1, []) + [id2] + dictA.get(id2, [])))
```

Running this results in

```
A   chr1    startA  endA    B   chr1    startB  endB
C   chr2    startC  endC    D   chr1    startD  endD
B   chr1    startB  endB    A   chr1    startA  endA
```

If I assume that I have `file1.txt` with contents

```
A   B
C   D
B   A
```

And `file2.txt` with contents

```
A,chr1,startA,endA
B,chr1,startB,endB
C,chr1,startC,endC
D,chr1,startD,endD
```

Then I can use the file read and write methods to generate your output

```
f1 = open('file1.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('file2.txt', 'r')
output_file = 'output.txt'

dictA = dict()
for line in f2:
    temp = line.strip().split(',')
    dictA[temp[0]] = temp[1:]
with open(output_file, 'w') as fp:
    for line in f1:
        id1, id2 = line.strip().split('\t')
        fp.write('\t'.join([id1] + dictA.get(id1, []) + [id2] + dictA.get(id2, [])) + '\n')
```

Comment: thank you..but could you pls use the file open and file write, bcos my files are big..this format is not comfortable at all...

Comment: How big are we talking here? Can we store the contents of file 2 in RAM or no?

Comment: not so big, but still 50k lines..and in the 2nd file i have 10 lines, I just shortened it here, so the file becomes quite massive

Comment: Edited to address using the actual files

Comment: Super, made it work as well in the meantime..thanks!